# Intellisense-like .Net Component?

Tags: .net, intellisense, components

does anyone know of any 3rd party component that provides an intellisense like functionality (providing my own library of course) that I could use in my (custom) text editor in order to improve usability?

Cheers & thanks,
-J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at ICSharpCode.TextEditor, which is included in [#develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/)

Comment: By the way, Scintilla.NET also provides that functionality. It's a managed wrapper for Scintilla, an unmanaged syntax-highlighting editor.

http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET

Comment: If you are now looking for ICSharpCode.TextEditor, it exists in #develop 3.2. Version 4 has replaced it with an alternative implementation (Avalon)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Actipro SyntaxEditor - Windows Forms .NET Control](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WindowsForms/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx).

Comment: +1 on that.  Been using this editor for years.  Great product, great support.

Comment: That one 'looks' good, but I am looking only for what they call the 'IntelliPrompt' feature.. and just got a reply from their support that it is hard-wired to the editor component and can't be used by it's own :-/